# Best practise to apply several rules on 1 string

Tags: python

i'm getting url as string and need to apply several rules to it. First rule is to remove anchors, then remove '../' notation, because urljoin joins url incorrect in some cases, and finally remove leading slash. For now i have such code:

```
def construct_url(parent_url, child_url):
        url = urljoin(parent_url, child_url)
        url = url.split('#')[0]
        url = url.replace('../', '')
        url = url.rstrip('/')
        return url
```

But i dont think this is the best practise. I think it can be done much simpler. Could you help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Do not try using regex (for this task)

Comment: @Anmol_uppal no. Just no. Using `urlparse.urlparse` is way less error prone than implementing a parser for URL schemes using regular expressions yourself.

Comment: Don't you think, that readability will been reduced if i will use regex?

Comment: @parikLS can you please give examples for what your `parent_url` and `child_url` look like? And what do you mean by *remove '../' notation, because urljoin joins url incorrect in some cases* - can you please give an example for that as well?

Comment: @LukasGraf Sure. parent_url = 'http://google.com' child_url = '../../../chrome' result of urljoin will be 'http://google.com/../../../chrome'

Comment: @parikLS ah. Well, `urljoin` does join that URL correctly though, it just doesn't *normalize* it. You may want to look at [python-urltools](https://github.com/rbaier/python-urltools) if you do actually need to normalize the URLs.

Comment: See [RFC 1808 Section 5.2: Abnormal Examples](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1808.html#section-5.2): *Parsers must be careful in handling the case where there are more relative path `".."` segments than there are hierarchical levels in the base URL's path.* So `urljoin` does exactly the right thing by preserving those extraneous `../`. If you want to remove them, you will need to do that manually.

Comment: @LukasGraf Got it. So i will remove relative path manually and for two other rules i will use urlparse.

Comment: @parikLS yep, that's what I would suggest. But it will probably be easier to use `scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment = urlsplit(joined_url)`, then do your processing, and use `final_url = urlunsplit((scheme, netloc, path, query, ''))` because you want to drop the fragment and process the `path` (trailing slashes and `../`), and the attributes on the `ParseResult` are read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't much that really could make your function *simpler* here, since you're dealing with some pretty odd cases.

But you can make it more *robust* by using Python's [`urlparse.urlsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) to split the URL in well-defined components, do your processing, and put it back together by using [`urlparse.urlunsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlunsplit):

```
from urlparse import urljoin
from urlparse import urlsplit
from urlparse import urlunsplit

def construct_url(parent_url, child_url):
    url = urljoin(parent_url, child_url)
    scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment = urlsplit(url)
    path = path.replace('../', '')
    path = path.rstrip('/')
    url = urlunsplit((scheme, netloc, path, query, ''))
    return url


parent_url = 'http://user:pw@google.com'
child_url = '../../../chrome/#foo'

print construct_url(parent_url, child_url)
```

Output:

```
http://user:pw@google.com/chrome
```

Using the tools from `urlparse` has the advantage that you know exactly what your processing operates on (path and fragment in your case), and it handles all the things like user credentials, query strings, parameters etc. for you.

---

**Note**: Contrary to what I suggested in the comments, `urljoin` does in fact normalize URLs:

```
>>> from urlparse import urljoin
>>> urljoin('http://google.com/foo/bar', '../qux')
'http://google.com/qux'
```

But it does so by strictly following RFC 1808.

From [RFC 1808 Section 5.2: Abnormal Examples](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808.html#section-5.2):

> Within an object with a well-defined base URL of
>
> Base: `<URL:http://a/b/c/d;p?q#f>`
>
> [...]
>
> Parsers must be careful in handling the case where there are more
> relative path `".."` segments than there are hierarchical levels in the
> base URL's path.  Note that the `".."` syntax cannot be used to change
> the `<net_loc>` of a URL.
>
> ```
> ../../../g    = <URL:http://a/../g>
> ../../../../g = <URL:http://a/../../g>
> ```

So `urljoin` does exactly the right thing by preserving those extraneous `../`, therefore you need to remove them by manual processing.